# Categorize the symbology using column "Type" by SVG symbols with a nested category using column "Hazard Risk" (Color) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg, categorized-renderer

I have point data and I already categorized it using specific SVG symbols. Now, what I want to do is to categorize further the SVG symbols by color (Low, Moderate, High, Very High).

[image]

Is there a faster way to do this?
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to use data defined override with a conditional expression?

Comment: Hi Erik! As long as it is easier to understand like simplified process to do the work. I recently explored the ruled-based symbology with an added categories for rule.

Comment: However, I find it tedious when categorizing. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Have you looked into data defined override for the colors?